# How to pass an object to an module in require.js?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have these js files:

main.js:

```
requirejs(['app']);
```

app.js:

```
define(['messages'], function (messages) {    
    alert(messages.getHello());
});
```

messages.js:

```
define(['global'],function () {
    var privateFn = global.getObj()

    return {
        getHello: function () {
            if(privateFn.hello == "test!")
                return 'Hello World';
        }
    };
});
```

global.js:

```
define(function () {
    var stateObj = {hello:"test!"};

    return {
         getObj: function () { return stateObj; }
    };
});
```

and index.html as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Include the RequireJS library. We supply the "data-main" attribute to let 
             RequireJS know which file it should load. This file (scripts/main.js) can
             be seen as the entry point (main) of the application. -->
        <script data-main="scripts/main" src="lib/require.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Example 2: load module using explicit dependency syntax</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

However when I open `index.html`, I get the below error in console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined  messages.js
```

where I'm making mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to set `global` as an argument to messages.js' function. requirejs will pass it in for you.

messages.js:

```
define(['global'],function (global) {
    var privateFn = global.getObj()

    return {
        getHello: function () {
            if(privateFn.hello == "test!")
                return 'Hello World';
        }
    };
});
```

This has the neat side effect that it is impossible to reference a module without declaring it as a dependency.